# How to send message from a Vuejs to Contact-Form-7 with Wordpress REST api?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, vue.js, contact-form-7, wordpress-rest-api

I installed **Contact-Form-7** in my WordPress admin panel and this give me an API Endpoint in `http://localhost/wordpress/wp-json/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms`

I tried to send a POST request to this endpoint with this code:

```
data() {
    return {
        form: {
            fullname: '',
            email: '',
            subject: '',
            message: ''
        }
    }
},
methods: {
    sendForm() {
        postRequest('/wp-json/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms', this.form)
        .then(response => {
            console.log('Success --> ' + response.data)
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('Error --> ' + error)
        })
    }
}
```

and what I response is

```
POST http://localhost:8080/wordpress/wp-json/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms 403 (Forbidden)
Error: Request failed with status code 403
```

Comment: `localhost:8080` and `localhost` are not the same domain authorization wise. Post to the domain on which your credentials are stored.

Comment: I set a proxy, it's fine, it works with other endpoints. The problem is not what you mentioned @kursus

Comment: Does it work with other endpoints that need authorization too ? In any case 403 means credentials are not properly transmitted. Can't really say more without further information.

Comment: Yes, It works with other endpoints, other endpoints don't need authentication to response @kursus

Comment: Then most likely your cookies aren't transmitted by your "proxy". It should work if you enter the full URL as stated in my first message.

Answer (score 0):

Post url must be

```
/wp-json/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/<FORM_ID>/feedback
```

by default, and form must be created in admin panel. It works for me.